# Restrict IE configuration changes from user in Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, admin, windows-7-x64

1. I want to create a user in windows.
2. And that user will not have permission to open any option from toolbar.
3. Also disabled toolbar for Developer tools(F12) of IE.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any toolbar but the F12 developer tools can be disabled with the registry setting:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IEDevTools]
"Disabled"=1

More over at:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/152554-internet-explorer-f12-developer-tools-enable-disable.html

Comment: Yeah, I can disable the F12 toolbar but can not find a way to disable developer tool's toolbar.